# Explain "C fundamentally has a corrupt type system"

Tags: c++, c, type-systems

In the book [Coders at Work](http://apress.com/book/view/1430219483) (p355), Guy Steele says of C++:

> I think the decision to be
>   backwards-compatible with C is a fatal
>   flaw. It’s just a set of difficulties
>   that can’t be overcome. **C
>   fundamentally has a corrupt type
>   system**. It’s good enough to help you
>   avoid some difficulties but it’s not
>   airtight and you can’t count on it

What does he mean by describing the type system as "corrupt"?

Can you demonstrate with a simple example in C?

**Edit**:

1. The quote sounds polemic, but I'm not trying to be. I simply want to understand what he means.
2. Please give examples in **C** not **C++**. I'm interested in the "fundamentally" part too :)

Comment: Oh dear, now you've done it.

Comment: Hmm, [Guy Steele again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689721/how-is-java-inspired-by-lisp)... (the C type system is unsafe, but I'm not sure what does he mean with "corrupt")

Comment: @Space: Yes it's deleted. You need 10k rep to read it.

Comment: @KennyTM: why can't I find the question you're linking to?

Comment: C and C++ only use type as a compile-time feature. You can override it by using ugly casts which means data is untyped. Contrast with, for example, Ruby where the contents (data) of a variable is typed. There is no way to corrupt a string by casting to int (like you can do in C++).

Comment: @Daniel, C++ have RTTI -- RunTime-Type-Infomation

Comment: I'm surprised people closed this. The *quote* is "subjective and argumentative", but trying to understand what it means is largely objective.

Comment: It's interesting that this "fatal flaw" is what allowed C++ to become one of the most widely used languages in the world. (and that the other hyper-popular language, Java, has a fundamentally flawed type system too, not because it can be circumvented without the compiler noticing, like in C++, but because it is unable to express even extremely simple concepts (like a generic `min` or `max` function). I'm not sure what the lesson here is, other than that apparently, languages need a "fatal flaw" or two in order to become popular.

Comment: @Manur: the problem is, as the close reason says, that questions of this type will "usually lead to confrontation and argument". Which is probably true here.

Comment: @Manur, I can see that part of the problem is that I'm asking people to guest what someone else means, which is definitely subjective. I just hoped there would be a reasonably simple, obvious answer :)

Comment: @Ian: Guy is, of course, setting out to be provocative. He thinks that type systems should prevent all bad things from happening, and that they are fundamentally guarantors of safety. C programmers don't think that way.

Comment: "I think the decision to be backwards-compatible with C is a fatal flaw." -> noone would use it if it weren't mostly backwards-compatible.

Comment: C has a type system?

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: Very good observation. If it weren't backwards compatible, it would have been done properly.

Comment: @jalf: I'd hardly call C++ "super popular". C and Java take the cake there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The obvious examples in C of non-type-safety simply come from the fact you can cast from void * to any type without having to explicitly cast so.

```
struct X
{
  int x;
};

struct Y
{
  double y;
};

struct X xx;
xx.x = 1;
void * vv = &xx;
struct Y * yy = vv; /* no need to cast explicitly */
printf( "%f", yy->y );
```

Of course printf itself is not exactly typesafe.

C++ is not totally typesafe.

```
struct Base
{
   int b;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  int d;

  Derived() 
  {
     b = 1;
     d = 3;
  }
};

Derived derivs[50];
Base * bb = &derivs[0];
std::cout << bb[3].b << std::endl;
```

It has no problem converting the Derived* to a Base* but you run into problems when you try using the Base* as an array as it will get the pointer arithmetic all wrong and whilst all the b values are 1 you may well get a 3 (As the ints will go 1-3-1-3 etc)

Comment: Java shouldn't let you do this either, but it does, and it creates its own problems.

Comment: @Ken: What Java allows is somewhat different.  For one thing, in Java you can't even create an array like that, the closest you can come is equivalent to the C code `Derived* derivs[50];`, and THAT isn't broken in C++ (you can't treat it interchangeably with `Base* [50]`).

Comment: @CashCow, just to be picky. In C you can't cast from `void*` to any other pointer type but only to pointers to data. It is not allowed to cast to function pointers.

Comment: I don't see this as a weakness. `void *` aren't particularly useful if you don't cast them to something. it's a real PITA in C++ having to cast everything left right and center.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: If you "have to cast everything left and right" in C++, you're doing something wrong

Answer (score 5):

Basically you can cast any data type to any data type

```
struct SomeStruct {
    void* data;
};

struct SomeStruct object;
*( (int*) &object ) = 10;
```

and noone catches you.

Comment: That's not C, furthermore casting turns off the type system, it isn't evidence of brokenness in the type system.

Comment: Yes, this looks like C++. Can you show an example of the same in C?

Comment: @Ben: yes it is. The type system controls which casts are allowed. And a cast that allows you to ignore the type system is a pretty good indication that the type system is broken (although this certainly doesn't mean that the *language* is broken. Or even that the type system is useless)

Comment: @jalf: Huh? There are no restrictions whatsoever on casts (you might need an address-of operator or two casts in a row, but I think you can get from any type to any other type).  In C, casting turns off the type system.  The fact that other languages define a type conversion operator that looks like a C typecast doesn't change this.

Comment: @Ben: you can get from any type to any other type without the type system catching you, sure, but doing so is undefined behavior in many cases. (think of the aliasing rules: you're not allowed to cast an `int*` to a `float*`, the compiler is just typically unable to prevent you from doing so.)

Answer (score 4):

```
char buffer[42];
FunctionThatDestroysTheStack(buffer);  // By writing 43 chars or more
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's a flaw in the type system.

Comment: A good example, but any language that supports direct unrestricted memory access allows you to easily write dreadful code, and all of them provide well-understood programming patterns to avoid those pitfalls. Bad programmer != bad language.

Comment: Well, Guy Steele's point is probably that any language that supports direct unrestricted memory access isn't as typesafe as Lisp, Ruby, Java, etc... and that most programmers don't need direct unrestricted memory access.

Comment: @KenBloom: Unrestricted memory access has nothing to do with the type system. (e.g. PEEK and POKE only take integer arguments)

Comment: Does C/C++, technically speaking, have "unrestricted memory access" though? In both languages, attempting anything like that is undefined behavior. It's not covered by the language, it's just that the compiler is typically unable to prevent you from doing it.

Comment: @jalf: "Undefined" by the C/C++ language doesn't usually mean simply that "the compiler is typically unable to prevent you from doing it." What it very often means is that "useful semantics can be plugged in here by your architecture/OS/compiler/etc..., but you'll have to look documentation outside the language standard to define the result, and the results may not be portable."

Comment: @Ken: The C++ standard has another term for that, typically "implementation dependent".

Comment: @Ken:  "Undefined" can mean several things.  Signed integer overflow is undefined in the sense you propose, and probably should be implementation-dependent.  Usually, "undefined" means "that's stupid, don't do that, but we're not going to require that the compiler catch you or require any specific behavior."

Comment: This alone is 50% of the reason C is the FASTEST language.

Comment: @Matt - not exactly true.  Decent JIT compilers can analyze the code well enough to see that a loop doesn't index an array out of bounds and omit the index check.  Safe and fast are incompatible goals.

Comment: @Hans: Decent static analyzers can figure that out too, and you don't even pay the startup cost of a JIT.  Plus, did you mean, are *not* incompatible goals?

Comment: I fumbled that comment pretty badly.  Redo: "@Matt - not exactly true. Decent JIT compilers can analyze the code well enough to see that a loop doesn't index an array out of bounds and omit the index check. Safe and fast *not* are incompatible goals."  Adding: the type system that jitters deal with allows this optim.  If the type system is fundamentally borked then there's little point in trying to burn cycles on "static analysis" on something you can't analyze anyway.  Which was the point of the question and the answer.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I'd agree that stronger typing should allow better compiler optimization. What I'd like to know is why the hell hasn't anyone done it? There are a few corner cases where C++ and Java (purely due to mainstream optimization effort) pull ahead, but in the main C is always faster. The stock response of "you get 80% of the performance for 20% of the effort" doesn't cut it. Those assumptions just rely on larger standard libraries.

Answer (score 3):

The C type system does have some problems.  Things like implicit function declaration and implicit conversion from `void*` can SILENTLY break type safety.

C++ fixes pretty much all of these holes.  The C++ type system is NOT backwards compatible with C, it's only compatible with well-written typesafe C code.

Furthermore, the people arguing against C++ typically point you to Java or C# as the "solution".  Yet Java and C# do have holes in their type system (array covariance).  C++ doesn't have this problem.

EDIT: Examples, in C++, attempting to use array covariance that would (improperly) be allowed by the Java and C# type systems.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {};

template<size_t N>
void func1( Base (&array)[N] );

void func2( Base** pArray );

void func3( Base*& refArray );

void test1( void )
{
  Base b[40];
  Derived d[40];

  func1(b); // ok
  func1(d); // error caught by C++ type system
}

void test2( void )
{
  Base* b[40] = {};
  Derived* d[40] = {};

  func2(b); // ok
  func2(d); // error caught by C++ type system

  func3(b[0]); // ok
  func3(d[0]); // error caught by C++ type system
}
```

Results:

```
Comeau C/C++ 4.3.10.1 (Oct  6 2008 11:28:09) for ONLINE_EVALUATION_BETA2
Copyright 1988-2008 Comeau Computing.  All rights reserved.
MODE:strict errors C++ C++0x_extensions

"ComeauTest.c", line 19: error: no instance of function template "func1" matches
          the argument list
            The argument types that you used are: (Derived [40])
        func1(d); // error caught by C++ type system
        ^

"ComeauTest.c", line 28: error: argument of type "Derived **" is incompatible with
          parameter of type "Base **"
        func2(d); // error caught by C++ type system
              ^

"ComeauTest.c", line 31: error: a reference of type "Base *&" (not const-qualified)
          cannot be initialized with a value of type "Derived *"
        func3(d[0]); // error caught by C++ type system
              ^

3 errors detected in the compilation of "ComeauTest.c".
```

This doesn't mean that there are no holes at all in the C++ type system, but it does show that you can't silently overwrite a pointer-to-Derived with a pointer-to-Base like Java and C# allow.

Comment: Java pre-generics was totally non-typesafe with containers as they all decayed to containers of objects so you could add any object to one.

Comment: @Ben: don't know what you mean by "covariance" in the array context (it's meaningless to me), but the problem is well known. Saying that C++ doesn't have this problem is incorrect. In C++ it's much worse, you get UB instead of a runtime exception. This is very well known. It's non-controversial to say that C++ type system is broken or corrupt. Don't confuse that with a value judgment.

Comment: @CashCow: It's my impression that this is still the case, due to the (broken) way generics are implemented in Java.

Comment: @Alf: Java and C#'s type system allows you to pass a reference to an array of references/pointers to a more derived class, and then store a reference/pointer to the base class.  In C++, you cannot.  I'll add some code examples to my answer.

Comment: Hm, I don't see why a `reinterpret_cast` in C++ is any "typesafer" than a `(void*)` in C.

Comment: @Jens: One is spelled `reinterpret_cast` (very easy to find), and the other is spelled `` (very hard to detect).

Comment: @Ben: Java has reference semantics, C++ has value semantics. In C++ passing an array of Derived where an array of Base is expected, can look like this: `void foo(Base a[]){ a[1]; } int main() { Derived a[5] = {}; foo( a ); }`. And in C++ it's Undefined Behavior. Cheers,

Comment: @Alf: C++ supports both reference and value semantics, and in the reference semantics case (the only one at all comparable to Java), it catches the error (see my `func1` example).  Yes there are some holes in the C++ type system, but the particular hole that Java (and C#) has is not present in C++.

Comment: @Ben: with demonstrated UB (my example above) in C++, due to corrupt C++ type system, what is there to discuss? It's silly of you to continue discussion after such example. The only thing left is whether C++'s worse problem is in a sense the same as the Java problem, or not. I say it's like (passing array of Derived where array of Base is expected -> oops), you say it's different (must be arrays of pointers in both languages, darnit!), and now I tell you, really, that detail doesn't matter a bit. Cheers,

Comment: @Alf: I agree.  Really the only thing that's different is that C++ gives you the ability to work around this issue (accept the array by reference, and your caller must pass you an array of that exact type) and Java does not.  And if you look closely, you'll see that I did look at both cases (array-of-values and array-of-pointers).  In C++, array-of-pointers is type-safe.  Array-of-values is not safe, by default, but a slight change to the function protects an unlimited number of callers against mischief.

Comment: @Ben: C++ does give ways to work around the issue, but the idea you mention is not a way. Passing raw array by reference, your idea, is generally not a practical proposition, since then you're fixing the array size at compile time. Your "unlimited number of callers" are calls that will never be made: nobody find fixed size arrays any attractive. As of 2010, that is. However, you can use `std::vector` and other such array abstractions, or define your own array abstractions, which is where C++'s strength lies: basic type system mostly corrupt, but good support for workarounds. Cheers,

Comment: Java and C# are definitely NOT the solution. I'd point at C as being the solution. It's simpler, easier to implement, work with, and limits the ridiculous implicit code generation and nonsense that C++ generates. Then there's the fact that C++ feels half done: Why on Earth am I allowed to leave members uninitialized in the constructor? I can't chain constructors? Why are we only getting variadic templates now? Why no VLAs? Why can I use struct OR class? No native string type? How about an Integer type? What's with the heap smashing? How about a REAL exception system.

Comment: @Matt: Arguing against yourself, aren't you?  In one comment you call implicit code generation "ridiculous", and then in the next sentence, complain that C++ doesn't have more of it.  In fact, everything after the word "generates" paints you with the "C#/Java troll" brush.  "How about an Integer type?"  c'mon, C++ has more integer types than any other language.  Did you mean a built-in BigInteger type?  That has all kinds of hidden costs and unexpected "code generation"?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: None of those things I mentioned _force_ additional implicit code beyond what C++ already requires (such as default methods on classes etc.). However they should certainly be revised and improved. 80% of the time I code in C++ I am patching holes such as exception safety, C type overflows, undefined variables, default methods, linker errors due to the ability to overload functions, behaviour of "implicit" code generated by templates, among more. C compatibility is there, but its useless without layers of meta nonsense.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I am the furthest one can be from a C#/Java troll, those languages *force* paradigms and platforms on you, while completely removing the programmer's freedom. At least C++ does not take that from you. Thank a god I am not forced to use libstdc++, which has to be the worst designed library I've encountered. Those integer types are straight from C, see my last comment. For the general case a "very wide integer", and builtin string would be far superior, see overflows, last comment. To finish, consider the inability to assign to containers sanely. Not cool.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to ask him what he meant to get a definitive answer, or perhaps provide more context for that quote.

However, it is pretty clear that if this is a fatal flaw for C++, the disease is chronic, not acute - C++ is thriving, and continually evolving as evidenced by ongoing Boost and C++0x efforts.

I don't even think about C and C++ as coupled any more - a few weeks on the respective *fora* here quickly cures one of any confusion over the fact that they are two different languages, each with its own strengths and foibles.

Comment: +1 for "foibles".  Almost Tolkenesque and gave me images of quaint villages and flaggons of ale.

Comment: I did not want to start a war by saying 'weaknesses'.

Comment: I would have used the word "eccentricities" but now I've got an image in my head of hobbits coding in C...

Comment: I think 'idioms' is the  least emotive option

Comment: @Frustrated:  Yeah, but you'd really think they'd be more into COBOL.  All except for a few.  The Tooks might get into C, the Brandybucks might even do a little Python when needed, but only Bilbo and Frodo and friends would try object-oriented or functional.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Except that quaint villages and flaggons of ale are only the start and end of LOTR. Perhaps this is a clue, most people never explore beyond the first few chapters of C before being frustrated at the mess they produce without someone (an overbearing language) telling them to "keep it secret, keep it safe".

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the "most broken" part of the C type system is that the concepts of

- values/parameters that are optional
- mutable values/pass-by-reference
- arrays
- non-POD function parameters

are all mapped to the single language concept "pointer". That means, if you get a function parameter of type `X*`, it might be an optional parameter, it might be expected that the function changes the value pointed to by `X*`, it might be that there are multiple instances of `X` after the one pointed to (it's open how many - the number could be passed as a separate parameter, or some kind special "terminator" value might mark the end of the array, as in nul-terminated strings). Or, the parameter might simply by a single structure, that you're not expected to change, but it's cheaper to pass it by reference.

If you get something of type `X**`, it might be an array of optional values, or it might be an array of simple values and you're expected to change it. Or it might be a 2d jagged array. Or an optional value passed by reference.

In contrast, take the ML family of languages (F#, OCaML, SML). Here these concepts map to separate language constructs:

- values that are optional have the type `X option`
- values that are mutable/pass by reference have the type `X ref`
- arrays have the type `X array`
- and non-POD types can be passed like PODs. Because they aren't mutable, the compiler can pass them by reference internally, but you don't need to know about that implementation detail

And you can of course combine those, i.e. `int optional ref` is a mutable value, that can be set to nothing or some integer value. `int ref optional` on the other hand is an optional mutable value; it can be nothing (and noone can change it) or it can be some mutable int (and you can change it to any other mutable it, but *not* to nothing).

These distinctions are very sublte, *but you have to make them whether you program in ML or not*. In C you have to make the same distinctions, but they're not explicitly stated in the type system. You have to read the documentation very carefully, or you might introduce sublte (read: hard to find) bugs if you misunderstand which kind of pointer usage is meant when.

Comment: You are probably right in many of your points, but I think you are exaggerating a bit. C since C89 has `T const*` to express when a parameter is not an "out" parameter, all others can be considered so. And since C99 has `T[static n]` to indicate that it expects an array of at least `n` elements.

Comment: @Jens, can you explain what you mean by an "out" parameter?

Comment: @Ian, `const` means not modifiable by the function, so it can only be read, and all others may be modified and may thus be used to return information to the caller.

Comment: I've never had a problem with this. :| This is what comments are for.

Comment: @Matt: Sure, you can live without any kind type system as long as you write decent commments, keep them up to date and every mainainance programmer reads them. But that wasn't the question.

Comment: @nikie: Good point (about the OP). Any maintenance programmer who comes in swinging will mess up, type system or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here, "corrupt" means that it is not "strict", leading to never-ending delight in C++ (because of the many custom types (objects) and overloaded operators, casting becomes a superior nuisance in C++).

The attack against C comes in regard to its MISPLACED USAGE as a strict OOP basis.

C has never been designed to limit coders, hence, maybe the frustration of Academia (and the flamboyant splendor of the ++ given to the World by B.S.).

*"I invented the term Object-Oriented, and I can tell you I did not have C++ in mind"*

(Alan Kay)